# Handling memory leak in cyclic graphs using RefCell and Rc

Tags: memory-management, graph, memory-leaks, rust

I followed the approach mentioned in https://ricardomartins.cc/2016/06/08/interior-mutability for creating a graph in Rust using `Rc` and `RefCell`.

```
type NodeRef<i32> = Rc<RefCell<_Node<i32>>>;

#[derive(Clone)]
// The private representation of a node.
struct _Node<i32> {
    inner_value: i32,
    adjacent: Vec<NodeRef<i32>>,
}
#[derive(Clone)]
// The public representation of a node, with some syntactic sugar.
struct Node<i32>(NodeRef<i32>);

impl<i32> Node<i32> {
    // Creates a new node with no edges.
    fn new(inner: i32) -> Node<i32> {
        let node = _Node { inner_value: inner, adjacent: vec![] };
        Node(Rc::new(RefCell::new(node)))
    }

    // Adds a directed edge from this node to other node.
    fn add_adjacent(&self, other: &Node<i32>) {
        (self.0.borrow_mut()).adjacent.push(other.0.clone());
    }
}
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Graph<i32> {
    nodes: Vec<Node<i32>>,
}

impl<i32> Graph<i32> {
    fn with_nodes(nodes: Vec<Node<i32>>) -> Self {
        Graph { nodes: nodes }
    }

}
```

I think this approach will lead to memory leaks in case of cyclic graphs. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to read a blog post to find the answer, just [read the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html):

> A cycle between `Rc` pointers will never be deallocated. For this reason, `Weak` is used to break cycles. For example, a tree could have strong `Rc` pointers from parent nodes to children, and `Weak` pointers from children back to their parents.

See also:

- [Is there a way to build a structure with cyclic links without runtime overhead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43824077/155423)
- [Implement graph-like datastructure in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34747464/155423)
- [Recursive Data Structures in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36167160/155423)

Comment: Well, so does that mean that for every edge you insert, you will look through the entire graph to check if this edge will create a cycle? I did read that you can use weak pointers in trees if you want children to point back to parents. But I am not sure how to translate that in case of graphs? What does it mean to have weak pointers in graphs?

Comment: @user9097180 you are about to embark on a journey of discovery around why exactly graphs are really hard concepts for memory management in both garbage-collected and non-GC languages. If you, the human, can't figure out a process to determine which links in a graph are strong and which are weak, how would the compiler / runtime? Maybe if your nodes have some ordering you could do strong references for "bigger" nodes and weak references for "smaller" nodes (I don't know if this will work).

Comment: @user9097180: At this point, you may want to look up the `petgraph` crate.

Answer (score -1):

Rust was not designed for programming structures with arbitrary back-links, like graphs. You will likely be looking for doing deallocation yourself so that you can keep arbitrary edges. Fortunately, Rust is flexible enough to allow your scenario almost seamlessly.

Here is one potential solution.
First, you define two macros for converting raw pointers back to borrowed pointers:

```rust
// Given a class or array pointer, transforms it to a mutable reference
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! modify {
    ($ptr:expr) => {
        (unsafe { &mut *$ptr })
    }
}

// Given a class or array pointer, transforms it to a read-only reference
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! read {
    ($ptr:expr) => {
        (unsafe { &*$ptr })
    }
}
```

Then, you modify your reference so that it's a real pointer. I'm adding methods below for checking if it's null or not, but you might as well use an option type if you prefer. Note that I changed your type parameter from `i32` to `I` as it's more idiomatic for type parameters to be uppercase.

```rust
type NodeRef<I> = *mut _Node<I>;
pub fn NullNodeRef<I>() -> NodeRef<I> {
    std::ptr::null_mut()
}
pub fn IsNullNodeRef<I>(node: NodeRef<I>) -> bool {
    node.is_null()
}
```

Now you can rewrite your node structure using the same layout:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
// The private representation of a node.
struct _Node<I> {
    inner_value: I,
    adjacent: Vec<NodeRef<I>>,
}
#[derive(Clone)]
// The public representation of a node, with some syntactic sugar.
struct Node<I>(NodeRef<I>);
```

When a node is dropped, its wrapper `_Node` needs to reclaim ownership to drop the underlying content.
To create a node, you need to allocate it on the heap, so that you can retrieve a stable address and Rust won't deallocate it.

```
impl <I> Drop for _Node<I> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        drop(unsafe { Box::from_raw(self.0) } );
    }
}

impl<I> Node<I> {
    // Creates a new node with no edges.
    pub fn new(inner: I) -> Node<I> {
        let node_ref =
          Box::into_raw(Box::new(_Node { inner_value: inner, adjacent: vec![] }));
        Node(node_ref)
    }
```

As a bonus, I'm adding a function to check if a node is the neighbor of another one, to demonstrate the use of the macro `read!()`:

```rust
    pub fn is_pointing_to(self, other: &Node<I>) -> bool {
        let this_node = self.0;
        let other_node = other.0;
        read!(this_node).adjacent.contains(&other_node)
    }
```

You original function `add_adjacent` can be conveniently rewritten using the `modify!()` macro. Note that cloning of references is no longer necessary as references have copy semantics.

```rust
    // Adds a directed edge from this node to other node.
    pub fn add_adjacent(&mut self, other: &Node<I>) {
        modify!(self.0).adjacent.push(other.0);
    }
}
```

Now you can define your graph. Because each of your Node will reclaim ownership of memory only when dropped, if you guarantee that no node or graph points to a node that was removed, then this is memory safe. With this approach, you cannot share nodes between graphs, but it's a good starting point you can generalize.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Graph<I> {
    nodes: Vec<Node<I>>,
}

impl<I> Graph<I> {
    fn with_nodes(nodes: Vec<Node<I>>) -> Self {
        Graph { nodes: nodes }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: Manually managing memory is error-prone, and I don't recommend doing it unless necessarily.
I invented these macros because I'm in charge of [writing the code generator from Dafny to Rust](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/blob/feat-rust/Source/DafnyRuntime/DafnyRuntimeRust/src/lib.rs#L2182), and Dafny is a safe language that does not have the concept of ownership, but could have safe deallocation. Hence, the code I generate will use all these macros but in a provably safe way. Manually using them is at your own risk and benefit.

However, with this approach, you can avoid any memory leak. You could also implement `Drop` for `Node` so that it will retake ownership of the  `_Node` below and clear it, so that the graph does not need to do it by itself.

Comment: Those macros are probably the most unsound things I've even seen. Don't do it. Also, the solution to graphs is not raw pointers, but [using some library](https://docs.rs/petgraph).